# How to publish/use a node module in laravel 5?

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs2

I have my `laravel` application and I'm starting to use `Vuejs`. I'm new with this and maybe I'm missing some core concepts.

Anyway (for example) I'd like to use this [component](https://monterail.github.io/vue-multiselect): A multiselect having a search-autocomplete.

After I run

```
npm install vue-multiselect@next --save
```

I have in my node_module the component dir, and I also have the dependency `vue-multiselect` in `package.json` file.

Now I'm a bit confused on how to move forward and use this component in one of my views.

The website installation is not going to work. I can't use require or import keywords in `common js`.

**Basic usage**

**Html**

```
<multiselect v-model="value" :options="options">
```

**JavaScript**

```
import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'

// register globally
Vue.component(Multiselect)

export default {
  // OR register locally
  components: { Multiselect },
  data () {
    return {
      value: null,
      options: ['list', 'of', 'options']
    }
  }
}
```

What's the correct way to install and use this component?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t66sakqx/) which will give you some idea.

Few things wrong I see in your code are:

1. HTML is just hanging, it should be in a template and id of that should be passed to el option of vue instance.
2. In the components in vue instance you need to use `Multiselect.Multiselect`

Comment: I'm still in trouble finding out how to Multiselect could be resolved. In fact I get a error online : components: { multiselect: VueMultiselect.Multiselect }, with VueMultiselect is not defined.